# Keyboard: How can I change the Sterling sign to Euro sign on 3, having Ubuntu installed on a MacBook?

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, macbook

My system is:

- OS: Ubuntu 20.10 x86_64
- Host: MacBook5,1 1.0
- Kernel: 5.8.0-44-generic

On terminal I have:

`$ cat /etc/default/keyboard`

- XKBLAYOUT=pt
- XKBVARIANT=mac_sundeadkeys
- BACKSPACE=guess

`$ setxkbmap -query -v 10`

> Applied rules from evdev:
> rules:      evdev
> model:      macbook79
> layout:     pt
> variant:    sundeadkeys
> options:    lv3:ralt_switch,compose:rwin,terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp
> Trying to build keymap using the following components:
> keycodes:   evdev+aliases(qwerty)
> types:      complete+numpad(mac)
> compat:     complete
> symbols:    pc+macintosh_vndr/pt(sundeadkeys)+inet(evdev)+level3(ralt_switch)+compose(rwin)+terminate(ctrl_alt_bksp)
> geometry:   macintosh(macbook79)
> rules:      evdev
> model:      macbook79
> layout:     pt
> variant:    sundeadkeys
> options:    lv3:ralt_switch,compose:rwin,terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp

`$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources`

- [('xkb', 'pt+mac_sundeadkeys')]

`$ xmodmap -pk | egrep "\(e\)"`

- 26 0x0065 (e) 0x0045 (E) 0x0065 (e) 0x0045 (E) 0x20ac (EuroSign) 0x0045 (E) 0x20ac (EuroSign)

`$ xmodmap -pk | egrep "\(3\)"`

- 12 0x0033 (3) 0x0023 (numbersign) 0x0033 (3) 0x0023 (numbersign) 0x00a3 (sterling) 0x00a3 (sterling) 0x00a3 (sterling)

Also, `gnome-tweaks` > Keyboard & Mouse > Additional Layout Options > Adding currency signs to certain keys does not have `Euro on 3`.

Finally, here's a [photo of the keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8Rsg.jpg).

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that by default you can type € via <AltGr>+E.

Comment: ubuntu custom keyboard shortcut to 'xdotool key ' then probably the sterling one   - here https://gitlab.com/cunidev/gestures/-/wikis/xdotool-list-of-key-codes  - EcuSign 0x10020a0 U+20A0 EURO-CURRENCY SIGN - set your shortcut key to the ound key on your keyboard. this could be done in a script to apply to only certain windows, testing for window title with xdotool getwindowname etc.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this would be with `xmodmap`. Changing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> from $ to € is as simple as doing this:

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Send an edit to `xmodmap`:

   ```
   xmodmap -e "keycode  12 = 3 EuroSign 3 EuroSign"
   ```

   This takes effect immediately and will persist until the next time you reboot, allowing you to try it out. If you'd like to set it back to the original value (without rebooting), you can do this via Terminal:

   ```
   xmodmap -e "keycode  12 = 3 dollar 3 dollar"
   ```

To make this setting permanent, you can create an `xmodmap` profile and have it load at boot. This is how you do it:

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. In your home directory, create a dot-file for the profile. For the sake of this example, I'll use `.xmodmap`:

   ```
   vi .xmodmap
   ```

   ***Note:** Feel free to use any text editor. It does not need to be* `vi`.
2. Add the `keycode` mapping:

   ```
   keycode  12 = 3 EuroSign 3 EuroSign
   ```
3. Save the file and exit the text editor
4. Create a file called `.xinitrc` in your home directory:

   ```
   vi .xinitrc
   ```
5. Add this line:

   ```
   xmodmap .xmodmap
   ```
6. Save the file and exit

Now every time you sign into Ubuntu, your <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> will be mapped to €.

***IMPORTANT:** If there are other people who use the computer who would also like this mapping, the steps above will need to be carried out for every user account.*

Comment: Now I have: Shift -> €; Alt -> £; and # disappeared.

Comment: I don’t understand the comment. *Just* the [Shift] key results in €? *Just* the [Alt] key results in £? And there is no further option for #? Is this correct? 

Comment: Yes to all your questions, indeed. Alt-E gives me € too.

Comment: Here's the output of [$ xmodmap -pke](https://pastebin.com/6WgUCzyK).